# dojo jax-rs call issue

Tags: dojo, jax-rs

I'm trying to call a REST webservice using dojo toolkit it seems that the call is encountring some isues this is the call with dojo

```
    dojo.xhrGet({
  url: 'http://localhost:9080/TestJMSWeb/jaxrs/categories/all',
  handleAs: 'json',
  timeout: 2000,
  load: callback
});
var callback = dojo.hitch(this, function(data) {
  var massagedData = {
    label: 'categorie',
    identifier: 'id',
    items: data
  }
  this.store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data: massagedData});
  });
```

the webservice code is here

```
@GET
    @Path("/all")
@Produces("application/json")
public JSONArray getAllCategories() throws IOException {
    final List<Categorie> allCategories = manager.getCategories();
    if (allCategories == null || allCategories.isEmpty())
        throw new WebApplicationException(ErrorUtil.jSONArrayResponse(Status.NO_CONTENT, "No category found"));
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonCustomerArray(allCategories);
    return jsonArray;

}
```

when I call the webservice I get an error message

```
ResourceRegis I org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry filterDispatchMethods The system cannot find any method in the ressources.CategorieRessouce class that supports OPTIONS. Verify that a method exists.
[4/24/12 1:23:41:531 GMT] 0000002f SystemErr     R 0  TestJMSWeb  INFO   [WebContainer : 0] openjpa.Runtime - OpenJPA dynamically loaded a validation provider.
```

it seems that is trying to call the ressource with the OPTIONS method while I'm using the .xhrGet function what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link describing the problem: http://engin.bzzzt.biz/2010/01/22/first-dojo-impression/

The guy talks about how if it is a cross domain request (which I believe yours is, because of the ports), and the request contains some Access-Control-* HTTP headers, than browsers will send the request as OPTIONS instead of GET.

Dojo adds the Access-Control-* headers when it determines you are making a cross domain request. You can try to fix this yourself by going to dojo/_base/xhr.js and commenting out the following lines (723 to 729):

```
// FIXME: is this appropriate for all content types?
if(args.contentType !== false){
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", args.contentType || _defaultContentType);
}
if(!args.headers || !("X-Requested-With" in args.headers)){
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
}
```

I haven't tried this fix yet so please let me know if it works!

Comment: before testing your solution
I have a trouble that I can't the data for security reasons
<br/>
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9080/TestJMSWeb/jaxrs/categories/all. Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: So your data is on localhost:9080 but your webapp with dojo is on localhost:8080? Even if you can't see the data or access it, that still shouldn't keep you from commenting out lines 723-729 in the dojo/_base/xhr.js file. Or are you saying that your webserver REQUIRES the Access-Control-Allow-Orgin header?